# Find escape Java and XML characters at the beginning of string

Tags: java, regex, xml, string, escaping

I'm trying to remove some characters at the beginning of the string. The string is taken from XML file and also escape characters of Java as well as XML.

For example, I have a string
`"'&amp;\\\'ab\t lkzv"` 
if, for instance, I would like to delete 2 characters the string should look like this
    `"\'ab\t lkzv"`
is there some simple way to do that?

I have tried to play with StringEscapeUtils.(un)escapeJava and StringEscapeUtils.(un)escapeXml but unfortunately those escapes also all non-english characters like Chinese, Arabic characters

Thanks for help,
Lucas

Comment: In your example string, does `\t` represent a single tab character, or the two characters U+005C U+0074?  It’s not clear what type of escape sequences you want to remove.

Comment: I'm looking to remove 1st x characters no matter whether they are escaped or unescaped characters either by Java or XML. I want to delete escaped characters from beginning as one which means that `&amp; ` or Java characters like `\\` are just one character. The problem is coming when I read strings from XML file that contains also escaped characters from Java for example `\t` in XML file is read as `\\\t` which are essentially 2 characters not just one